# What is wrong with my attempt to use EntityFramework to execute a sql statement

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

The following works:

```
var s = string.Format("drop table {0};", tableName);
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(s);
```

But to avoid injection I'm trying to use the parameter version

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"drop table {0};", tableName);
```

however this is giving me an error **"Incorrect syntax near '@p0'."**

I've tried **?** as well, but I get similar results.

Comment: What is the source of `tableName`? and what is the reason for this requirement?

Comment: This _is_ SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table name can't be parameterised.

To avoid injection the best you can do is emulate the TSQL [QUOTENAME](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) function. Ensure the table name is no longer than 128 characters. Wrap it in `[]` and replace any embedded `]` with `]]`.

Executing a `DROP TABLE` based on arbitrary user input sounds highly unusual/problematic in itself though.